# Regex for finding value inside url in background-url

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, regex

1. I have `$('#tab1').css("background-image", "url(../CARImages/Icons/tab1.png)");` I need to extract `../CARImages/Icons/tab1.png` from this.
2. I may have `background-image:url(../Images/Themes/tile_bg.png);` syntax in css. I need to extract `../Images/Themes/tile_bg.png` from this.
3. Syntax can be background:url("../Images/bg_topnav.gif"); I need to extract ../Images/bg_topnav.gif from this.

4.. Syntax can be background:url('../Images/bg_topnav.gif'). I need to extract ../Images/bg_topnav.gif from this.

Can I have same Regex for the above syntax to extract image reference.

Output should not contain inverted comas, which are present in the original syntax.

Comment: You have at least 2 questions that you've duplicated each -- please don't do this. If your question isn't getting attention, edit it with additional details and it will be bumped back up in the queue. Posting it a second time isn't acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

use this:

```
/url\([\"\']?(.*?)[\"\']?\)/
```

demo  : http://rubular.com/r/EXrGNXnmnn

for eg :

```
var str = '$(\'#tab1\').css("background-image", "url(../CARImages/Icons/tab1.png)");';
var res = /url\([\"\']?(.*?)[\"\']?\)/.exec(str);
console.log(res[1]);
```

regex with look behind

```
(?<=url)\([\"\']?(.*?)[\"\']?\)
```

Comment: I dont want url to get prefixed to the image reference. I just need the value inside parenthesis. In this, I am getting url("../Images/bg_topnav.gif"). I just want ../Images/bg_topnav.gif.

Comment: you will get that only if you look at the matched groups carefully

Comment: I had this Regex (?<=url\().*?(?=\)), But I used to get inverted comas  also with this regex. If possible, can you please edit this regex, so as to not get inverted comas, but only Image reference.

Comment: This wont work in this case, Please provide Regex to get only Image reference inside url:("").

Comment: You can use this regex to find value of `background-image` attribute, then after you extract `url()`, `url('')`, etc.

Comment: @Kanaiya Sorry but I dont understand what you cannot get. The image reference inside url is the part coming in the capture group. I have edited your regex with lookbehind also.

Comment: I have a delegate, which matches the Regex and gives the output, which I have mentioned. So I just need 1 regex, which can provide the desired above 4 outputs, since I cannot hard code in my function, based on the value inside parenthesis.
Because if I use capture group for individual syntax, it would be like doing hard code, which is not appreciable. 
Please let me know, if I can get Regex similar to the one, I provided, but with no inverted comas. only image values.